# How do I shrink a Win Srv 2k12R2 disk in VMWare ESXi 6.0?

Tags: windows

I have a virtual Win Srv 2k12R2 running with 250GB on "D:\", but I need to shrink it to free some space in my storage. I want to resize it to 100GB.

From what I learnt on the webz, I'd have to use the VMWare Converter to rebuild the VM and select a smaller disk during the virtualization process. I also learnt I'd need a free space to create a snapshot from that machine, which I don't have - hence why I wanna free some space.

I know I can't do this live, but I want to minimize the impact as much as it's possible, since this server runs my BI application 24/7.

Question 1: Can I just shrink it via Windows and then shrink via vCenter?

Question 2: If doing what I want is possible, will it really free the space I need?

Comment: How much free space you have in your datastore

Comment: Not much, actually... it has less than 200GB free and I have at least 5 more machines running on it.